# bundle install --deployment wrong number of

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have this line in the Gemfile:

```
gem "acts_as_versioned", :git => 'https://github.com/rtacconi/acts_as_versioned.git'
```

On two servers bundle install in deployment mode works, but in one server I get this:

```
  * executing "cd /path_to_app/releases/20130705120639 && bundle install --gemfile /path_to_app/releases/20130705120639/Gemfile --path /path_to_app/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["173.255.196.228"]
    [173.255.196.228] executing command
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:   8% (1/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  16% (2/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  25% (3/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  33% (4/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  41% (5/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  50% (6/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  58% (7/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  66% (8/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  75% (9/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  83% (10/12)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Unpacking objects:  91% (11/12)
Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done. objects: 100% (12/12)   
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] An error occurred while installing acts_as_versioned (0.6.1), and Bundler cannot
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] continue.
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] Make sure that `gem install acts_as_versioned -v '0.6.1'` succeeds before
 ** [out :: 173.255.196.228] bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try drop bundler to prisitne state:

```
gem pristine bundler
```

Other than that, I would try `gem update bundler` as well.